# Update Asset Index in Migration

Tags: craft3, php, migration

I'm trying to index some asset volumes that I'm creating in a migration. These are local volumes which may already contain files.

I'm hoping to avoid the step where I have to manually update the asset indices after creating volumes.

The following code does not seem to perform the index, am I missing a step? I've studied the controller used by Utilities but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
    $volumeId = Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle('myVolume')->id;

    $indexer = Craft::$app->getAssetIndexer();

    $sessionId = $indexer->getIndexingSessionid();

    $indexer->processIndexForVolume($sessionId,$volumeId);
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hey,  no I never did. I've tried digging through the services Craft itself uses for this but I don't have enough experience with that side of the application to extract anything of use. It would be nice if there was a service you could just hit but it doesn't appear to be that simple.

Comment: Have you tried downloading and reverse engineering plugins that need to do something similar? I tend to start there when there isn't clear documentation or SO questions to help me out. Check out the plugin store and see if asset related plugins have Craft 2 versions. The Craft 3 version would likely need to do some migrations.

Answer (score 3):

As of 3.1.2 you can now index assets via the cli tool:

```
./craft index-assets/all
```

OR

```
./craft index-assets/one {handle}
```